# Pyinstaller wait until script has finished?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I have made my exe file(it works) but I have one problem: the exe closes before it should finish. Is their a parameter to stop this? Here is the command I used:
`pyinstaller --onefile -w --hidden-import="requests" "main.py"`

Comment: _"the exe closes before it should finish"_: What does that mean?

Comment: Its supposed to send a discord webhook, I open it with cmd and the regular file and it works, when I use the exe it instantly closes and does not complete the code. @Selcuk

Comment: Can you post the relevant portions of your code? What do you see when you execute the `.exe` from the command prompt? Any error messages?

Comment: Their is no error, the console shows up and does its thing then instantly closes. Im trying to let it finish before it closes the exe.

Comment: Post a [mcve] so we can help you out. This includes version numbers of software/libs. End of Review.

Comment: You created a 'windowed' application, it is normal that the exe closes quickly (usually the exe continues running in the background) when ran from CLI (because stdin/out/err are 'patched'). Otherwise make a console application (omit `-w`).